# Oozie workflow import failed in hue

Tags: hadoop, oozie

i'm unable to import oozie workflow in hue editor, hue version 2.5.0

Error : **Could not import workflow, Node kill has not been defined**

```
<workflow-app name="mapDeply" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
        <start to="TestPOC"/>
        <action name="TestPOC">
            <java>
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <prepare>
                      <delete path="${nameNode}/data/temp"/>
                </prepare>
                <main-class>WordCount</main-class>
                <arg>/data/input</arg>
                <arg>/data/temp</arg>
            </java>
            <ok to="end"/>
            <error to="killemail"/>
        </action>
        <action name="killemail">
            <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
                <to>test@test.com</to>
                <subject>Test</subject>
                <body>TEST</body>
            </email>
            <ok to="kill"/>
            <error to="kill"/>
        </action>
        <kill name="kill">
            <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
        </kill>
        <end name="end"/>
    </workflow-app>
```

if i change java action error to kill it's working. is this excepted behavior or is there any work around to resolve it

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not supported. You indeed need to have each action error node point to the kill node, then import the workflow, then modify it in the editor.

This will be improved in the future and this use case can be in part replaced by the [Oozie SLA](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/oozie/DG_JMSNotifications.html), supported up in [Hue 3.6](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/730827/cloudera/20140111_slamagic.mp4).